# Python 3 .csv not writing

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I am trying to insert quiz results from a quiz into a .csv file however the results are not being written into the file after it is created.

```
file_writer = csv.writer(open('Class Results.csv', 'w'), delimiter=',')  
file_writer.writerow((name, Class, score))
```

Is any other part of my code required?

Answer (score 0):

You never store or close the file object, the result is written when the file object is closed.

```
with open('Class Results.csv', 'w') as f:
    file_writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    file_writer.writerow((name, Class, score))
```

Comment: Thanks! However I am now having trouble making the .csv write on consecutive lines instead of overwriting the first one each time, any ideas?